# Lost account after changing default Google account

Tags: support

Google made me change my default e-mail address to a GMail one a couple of months back and now I can't log into StackOverflow.  I have tried to Restore my account on the log-in screen but have had no joy.

Is there a way of getting my old account back?

Comment: I can't +1 this question because, of course, my reputation was lost when my account became inaccessible.

Stackoverflow folks: If you want to know the scope of this issue, count Google accounts whose email is not @gmail.com